# How to transform equation and leave X alone

Tags: logarithms

i need to transform this equation and leave x alone on the left, y and z bot on the right. like `x = ...` . Is it possible to do it? `y` and `z` are my variables. Also prefer $\pi$ to remain same if possible.

$$y = z\Bigg(0.5 - \frac{log\Big(\frac{1+\sin(x*\frac{\pi}{180})}{1-\sin(x*\frac{\pi}{180})}\Big)} {4 \pi}\Bigg)$$

**Edit:**
I came up to this point, does this make any sense or am i just embarrass myself in front of you guys.

*Removed my equation because it was wrong*

If this is correct (I doubt it) how can i get rid of sin on the right hand side?

Comment: what Kind of $\log$ is this?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner i'm so sorry but couldn't understand what you mean. I'm not a math guy i'm afraid. Just trying to reverse a calculation used in a geographical calculation software program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Let $a=\sin (\frac {x\pi}{180}) $.
$$b=\frac {1+a}{1-a}=-1+\frac {2}{1-a} $$

$$b=e^{4\pi (0,5-\frac {y}{z})} $$

$$a=1-\frac {2}{b+1} $$
$$x=\frac {180}{\pi}\arcsin (a) $$

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. I edited my question and added what i did, hope it's correct. So now what's about sine?

Comment: @Ergec Your result is not correct.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the final equation. But when i put my values into equation i don't get the expected result. Z = 256, Y = 101.26823920973 and for these two values X must have 35.152840 but it doesn't.

Comment: Is your logarithm Neperian or Decimal. May be you should replace 10 by e=2,7.

Comment: This is brilliant :) seems it's `e` not `10` . You're a life saver, thanks a lot.